# В чем разница asp.net core на .NET Framework и на .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Я могу создать проект asp.net Core используя .NET Core или .NET Framework.
Архитектура кода остается одинаковой в обоих случаях.
Но в чем-то будет принципиальная разница, кроме того, что один проект будет использовать .NET Framework плюс библиотеки .NET Core ?

Используя .NET Framework я могу что-то потерять и есть ли большие приемущества в использовании того или инного варианта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это отвечает на все мои вопросы?
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server
Или может есть ещё что-то?

Comment: `.Net Core` - рассчитана прежде всего на кроссплатформ. разработку, т.е. должна работать в среде различных ОС. `.Net Framework` - сугубо виндовая история. Если создаете проект `ASP.NET Core` и планируете его запускать только на винде, то выбор .Net Framework очевиден, т.к. при этом выборе вы получаете поддержку всех возможностей фрейворка, в случае же .Net Core придется пожертвовать рядом возможностей в пользу возможности запуска проекта на Linux & Mac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**.NET Core** - мультиплатформенный среда исполнения для консольных и Web приложений, программы сделанные на ней можно запускать на Winows, Linux, MacOs

Плюсы: кроссплатформенность, opensource.

**.NET Framework** - среда исполнения под Windows.
Создание классических Windows-приложений и веб-приложений ASP.NET для IIS.

Плюсы: большое количество уже написанных библиотек кода, более широкие возможности по сравнению с .NET Core.

На данный момент Microsoft очень активно развивает Core ветку, и быстрыми темпами наращивает функционал.
Лично для себя сейчас выбираю .Net Core, как более перспективную в будущем, при этом мне её функциональности хватает.
Многие NuGet модули, библиотеки постепенно адаптируются для .NET Standart, а тем самым и для Core.

Почитать можно [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/340128/).

Comment: Хостинг под ASP.NET Core под Linux - любой хостинг, умеющий хостить докер контейнеры - тот же Azure App Services/ AKS, Amazon ECS,  Heroku, Kubernetes в Google Cloud Platform...

Comment: @PashaPash хм... я искал просто в яндексе и гугле что-то типа ASP.NET Core Linux hosting. Ничего не нашёл подобного. Хотелось бы что бы он нативно поддерживался хостером.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под "нативно"? хостерам гораздо проще поддерживать "все что угодно в линуксовом контейнере", так что контейнеры - это и есть "нативная" поддержка - собираете образ на основе https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/, запускаете на любом хостинге с поддержкой контейнеров. это и есть основное преимущество .net core - его не нужно ставить, под него не нужен специфический хостинг - любой сойдет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин уточнение: библиотеки переписываются обычно все же не под Core, а под Standard

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за уточнение, не знал, надо будет почитать про контейнеры, а вы пробовали ставить на Linux, какие успехи? Если готовы полноценно ответить, я могу новым вопросом сформулировать, интересен полноценный ответ.

Comment: @PavelMayorov обновил ответ с учётов ваших рекомендаций.

Answer (score -2):

Разная среда выполнения - для быстроты разработки можно отлаживать программы на классическом IIS сервере, при этом со штатным дебагом в Visual Studio и накопленным с 2007 года ПО, но не факт, что программа потом заработает после запуска через

```
dotnet run
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Плюсы:**

1. Скорость запуска
2. Выбор как и в обычном ASP.Net в виде запуска на IIS Express или его эмуляторе
3. Расширения для браузера, помогающие Visual Studio отлаживать код

**Минусы:**

1. Запуск не на той же виртуальной машине, что работает на Mac и Linux, соответственно может не заработать

**Вывод:**

Если необходимо найти конкретный баг, то можно использовать. Но лучше переходить на Visual Studio Code и консоль