# Общая доменная логика: .Net Standard или .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, xamarin

Пробую создать демо-решение "Записная книжка" (база контактов), в котором было бы несколько приложений под разные платформы.

Как я себе это видел. База данных будет на MS SQL, будет обычный asp.net mvc веб-сайт (это типа приложение номер раз - для тех, кто пойдёт через браузер), отдельно будет asp.net web api, которое будет отдавать чистый json для мобильных приложений и отдельно будет пара приложений (одно под андроид, одно под ios). В VS2017 есть проект xamarin.forms с готовым шаблоном прямо специально заточенным под показ списка контактов - Master Detail, остаётся только MockDataStore перепилить с List на сервис, читающий из web api.

[image: Solution structure]

Собственно, ради приложения под андроид всё и затевалось, хотелось попробовать мобильную разработку. Однако что-то у меня не стыкуется с тем, как состыковать столь разнородные приложения.

Я создал проект Domain (обычная class library), в который поместил класс Contact и попробовал заменить модель Item из проекта мобильного приложения на свою модель, однако даже простое перемещение решарпером класса Item в Class Library .Net Framework приводит к ошибке (Domain should reference Assembly:netstandard).

[image: Move class]

К слову, та же самая ошибка даже если пробовать переместить в проект Class Library .Net Standard. Насильственное перемещение приводит к множеству ошибок компиляции.

[image: Compile error]

Окончательно рвёт шаблон то, что при попытке подключить в проект assembly через reference - add reference никаких assembly со словом net или standard на компе нет.

Итого.

Непонятно:

- как создавать проект доменной логики: как .Net Framework или как .Net Standard. Для ASP.Net MVC нужна обычная .Net Framework, какая нужна приложениям Xamarin вообще непонятно
- где найти Assembly:netstandard
- возможно, что для подобных мультипроектов нужно отказываться от классического приложения asp.net mvc и заменять их на asp.net core (в них я видел при создании [выбор между .net core и .net framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/761460/213987)), чтобы все проекты шли на одном технологическом стеке ([раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314588/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/312026/))

[image: technology stack]

Comment: А если создать доменной проект типа net standard?

Comment: В случае Xamarin для библиотек общих классов лучше использовать .NetStandard 2.0. Отсюда вытекает, что для web надо использовать Asp.Net Core. Когда вы используете шаблон Xamarin для создания нового проекта, то не торопитесь обновлять встроенные библиотеки до последних версий, иначе будете получать вот такие вот предупреждения и ошибки как у вас на скриншотах (о не соответствии версии проекта и версий подгруженных библиотек).

Comment: @Bulson Похоже, что год назад вы что-то успели поковырять в xamarin, прежде чем забросили ;)

Comment: Да, я его пытался изучать, но честно пока забросил. Гладко было на бумаге, да забыли про овраги... - это в полной мере про Xamarin. Да, на простых демонстрашках все вроде как работает, но в след. цикл обновления SDK со стороны Google все ранее написанные проекты начинают сыпать как из пулемета ошибками и предупреждениями, в общем много боли...

Comment: + к сказаному про Xamarin, я пока переключился на изучение Asp.Net Core. Рекомендую обратить на этот свежий фреймворк пристальное внимание, за ним будущее.

Comment: Вроде бы вполне обычная ошибка - у вас класс  Contact не объявлен (или находится в сборке, на которую из вашей App3.Models нет ссылки). Из-за этого App3.Models просто не собирается, и дальше вы получаете каскад ошибок. Т.е. да, вы все правильно делаете - общий код выносите в .net standard class lib, и добавляете на него references из других проектов. Просто вы пытаетесь собрать нерабочий код :)

Comment: @Bulson asp.net core != .net core. это неудачный подбор названий. asp.net core вполне работает под full .net framework. И из использования .net standard никак не вытекает необходимость использования asp.net core - даже наоборот, использование .net standard позволяет разделять код между проектами на старом asp.net, asp.net core, и всеми остальными платформами, которые его реализуют.